# Tabbed Navigation Menu Responsive

Tags: html, css, tabs, responsive

I am working through the W3Schools tab and navigation menu sections. I have created a tabbed navigation menu that I would like to make responsive, but have been unable to figure out how to do it. I believe it will involved the use of @media query, but I am not sure exactly how to do it. Below is my code. Some help would be much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="tab">
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Red')">Red</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Blue')">Blue</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Green')">Green</button>
</div>
</div>

<div id="Red" class="tabcontent">
<p>Test</p>
<p><b><ins>2018</ins></b></p>
<ul>
<li><a href=#>Test1</a></li>
</div>

<div id="Blue" class="tabcontent">
<p>Test2</p> 
</div>

<div id="Green" class="tabcontent">
<p>Test3</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
 /* Style the tab */
.tab {
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: black;
max-width: 75%;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
background-color: inherit;
border: none;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 14px 16px;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 20px;
width: 33.1%;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: arial;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
background-color: slategray;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
background-color: red;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
display: none;
padding: 6px 12px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-top: none;
font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: When you say you're "*working through the W3 tab and navigation sections...*" do you mean [W3Schools.com](http://w3schools.com), or the [World Wide Web Consortium (W3)](http://w3.org/)? Because W3Schools is many things, but it's absolutely not, in any way at all, connected to the W3 organisation. The misleading name being only one of the complaints against W3Schools.

Comment: I am talking about W3Schools tutorials.